# How do I convert C.AVFrame* to image.Image?

Tags: c, go, ffmpeg

I have C.AVFrame* raw image.

After converting from C.AVFrame* to jpg, I am dealing with Go images after jpg decoding.

Is there any way to create Go image directly from C.AVFrame*?

Comment: No, there is no instant way to do it. You have AVFrame is a structure in C languagge, where the image.Image is std lib golang part. image package does not know anything about the AVFrame. You need to implement your own function. There is another way encoder, you can take a look how to implement it and revert algorithm: https://github.com/pwaller/go-ffmpeg-video-encoding/blob/master/ffmpeg.go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good place to start: https://github.com/nareix/joy4/blob/05a4ffbb53695aaacf9a2e2624472686280ab6dc/cgo/ffmpeg/video.go#L64-L88

Once you have the `*C.AVFrame` as `frame` you could:

```golang
func fromCPtr(buf unsafe.Pointer, size int) (ret []uint8) {
    hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)((unsafe.Pointer(&ret)))
    hdr.Cap = size
    hdr.Len = size
    hdr.Data = uintptr(buf)
    return
}


w := int(frame.width)
h := int(frame.height)
ys := int(frame.linesize[0])
cs := int(frame.linesize[1])

img = image.YCbCr{
    Y: fromCPtr(unsafe.Pointer(frame.data[0]), ys*h),
    Cb: fromCPtr(unsafe.Pointer(frame.data[1]), cs*h/2),
    Cr: fromCPtr(unsafe.Pointer(frame.data[2]), cs*h/2),
    YStride: ys,
    CStride: cs,
    SubsampleRatio: image.YCbCrSubsampleRatio420,
    Rect: image.Rect(0, 0, w, h),
}
```

To populate the image in an `image.YCbCr` which implements `image.Image`